# Python: how to extract the LAST substring of a string with separator into another column?

Tags: python, delimiter

I have a dataframe with a column "CCR" whose values are as such : "Aaaa;Bbbb;Cccc", or "Bbbb;;Cccc", or "Cccc;Bbbb;Aaaa" or just "Bbbb".
I would like to extract the last substring part (after the ";") and put it into another column "LastCCR".
If there is only one value and therefore no ';' then the value stays the same in the LastCCR column.

I would like to use a lambda function: I used the code line below to extract the FIRST value but I don't know how to alter it so as to extract the LAST value of my string.
Can anyone help ?

```
df[1stCCR] = df['CCR'].apply(lambda x:x[0:x.index(';') if ';' in x else None])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[1stCCR] = df['CCR'].apply(lambda x: x.split(";")[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.extract` we can try:

```py
df["LastCCR"] = df["CCR"].str.extract(r'([^;]*)$')
```